# Using result from python further down in a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I am using a batch file to run 2 python scripts and one executable (the executable here isn't important, I'm just giving context).

What I am confused about, and I have done some searching on google and here specifically, is outputting and retrieving variables directly from the console using python.

For example, my first python script with produce a date:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_date():
    today = datetime.today()
    run_date = today - timedelta(1)
    return run_date
```

What I want is for that returned `date` (which will be a string of specified format) to be available in the command line as it will be used as a parameter in the executable and passed into a 2nd python script as an argument.

I basically want it to have the same effect as:

```
set Date = <some date>

python script_2.py Date
```

Except `<some date>` will be the returned `run_date` value from the first script.

Apologies if this is simple and common knowledge, but this is the first time I've ever tried to make a series of scripts that interact with eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to output the result in the console to catch the value with a `FOR` loop

An example :

GetDate.py :

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print today
```

test.bat :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('GetDate.py') do set "$date=%%a"
echo the recuperated date is %$date%
```

Comment: And then that is stored as a variable inside the console which can later be used as a parameter for an executable call or as an argument in a 2nd python script?

Comment: It is stored as `%$date%`